# How to adjust CSS for specific zoom level?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have built a website using bootstrap 3, every time I open the web site I have to adjust the zoom level in the browser to 90%-80% in order to get better looking and show more on the page. 
My question is what zooming actually doing to the CSS, and is it possible to configure bootstrap in a way to give me the same result on 100% zoom level as I do on 90%?

Comment: Welcome to SO, this is not a 'help me code site'. You need to produce your attempt to the problem so far. Kindly go through this post for more info - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What parts are looking bad, fonts, width of the page ect?

Answer (score 1):

I believe zoom of 90% should be identical to

```
body {
  transform: scale(0.9);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

(in everything except IE<9)

Answer (score 1):

For bootstrap 3, you can generate a custom version of the library using the configuration tool and change the `@font-size-base` parameter: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/.

It is a bit different with bootstrap 4. Bootstrap 4 uses `rem`s for defining most sizes (1 rem is equal to the default font size). 
You can redefine the value of the `rem` with the following css :

```
body {font-size:14px}
```